# Cannot launch Ubuntu after installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, grub-efi

I have windows 10 on my machine and I decided to install Ubuntu 16 alongside it.

After the installation process there is no GRUB and I cannot launch Ubuntu. I tried to launch it by manually choosing Ubuntu from boot devices but it says boot device not found.

I turned off fast boot and tried to install again. It did not work. I tried to turn on legacy boot and install again. This did not work either. I tried to put recovery USB drive of Windows 10 and install Ubuntu again. This failed as well.

I tried to repair MBR through command prompt. All the operations were successful but I still cannot launch Ubuntu. I am stuck now and do not know what to do.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair you can try this if you manage to boot in Live mode

Comment: and What is **did not work**? what errors did you get? where did you stop? did the installer start? give us more information we'd be glad to help

Comment: As I was instaling ubuntu there was no errors, but after instalation the is no grub where you can choose operating system. I tried diffrent methods(listed in my first question) to solve it but still there is no grub. When I press f9 to chose boot source,on the list I can find ubuntu but when I choose it it says boot device not found error 3f0

Comment: when you installed it for the first time, did you get  "**Grub installation failed, system will not boot**" something like that error

Comment: No I did not get any errors during the instalation and after the instalation. Still I did not get grub to choose the operating system.

Comment: Please read the first answer in the following question carefully and check if it can solve your problem or not:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Your **boot flag must be set set to the wrong partition**.

Same happened with me when I dual boot ubuntu and windows but couldn't load any.

So, try checking the partitions using any partition editor.

Since none of your OS is loading up, you should **boot using GParted live usb**.

Then in partition manager, **check for the boot flag.**

It must be set to the partition where the  /root is installed.